# how nodejs http.request send json params to java interface

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, json

we have a java interface to send verify_code to the phone,and it was woking fine on postman。

[image: postman]

my nodejs code as below

```
let test = {
        "phoneNumber": "15021071273",
        "smsParams": [
            "注册",
            "123456",
            "注册"
        ],
        "tmplId": 109341
    }

    var content = JSON.stringify(test);

    // An object of options to indicate where to post to
    var post_options = {
        host: '172.16.211.33', //'common-message'
        port: '10011',
        path: '/sms/sendTecentyunSms',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': content.length
        }
    };

    // Set up the request
    var post_req = http.request(post_options, function (res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
        });
    });

    // post the data
    post_req.write(content);
    post_req.end();
```

and the java interface reponses:

> Response: {"timestamp":1572935973619,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"JSON parse error: Unexpected end-of-input within/between Object entries; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input within/between Object entries\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@3e497877; line: 1, column: 157]","path":"/sms/sendTecentyunSms"}

looks like it's just a json parsing error.

I also tried to JSON.stringy the tese.smsParams first,not working

req.write only accept a string or a buffer,so it can't just put a json object as a param。

Comment: can you try test = '{ "phoneNumber": "15021071273",.....}' instead stringfy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this way

```
var http = require('http')

var body = JSON.stringify({
        "phoneNumber": "15021071273",
        "smsParams": [
            "注册",
            "123456",
            "注册"
        ],
        "tmplId": 109341
    })

var request = new http.ClientRequest({
    hostname: "172.16.211.33",
    port: 10011,
    path: "/sms/sendTecentyunSms",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Content-Length": Buffer.byteLength(body)
    }
})

request.end(body)


request.on('response', function (response) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + response.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(response.headers));
  response.setEncoding('utf8');
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var content = JSON.stringify(test);

    // An object of options to indicate where to post to
    var post_options = {
        host: '172.16.211.33', //'common-message'
        port: '10011',
        path: '/sms/sendTecentyunSms',
        body:content,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': content.length
        }
    };
```

---

Or try the `request` module

```js
const request = require('request');

let test = {
    "phoneNumber": "15021071273",
    "smsParams": [
        "注册",
        "123456",
        "注册"
    ],
    "tmplId": 109341
}

var content = JSON.stringify(test);

// An object of options to indicate where to post to
var post_options = {
    method: 'post',
    url:"http://172.16.211.33:10011/sms/sendTecentyunSms",
    body:content
};

request(post_options,(err, res, body) => {
  if (err) { return console.log(err); }
  console.log(body.url);
  console.log(body.explanation);
});
```

you can play with it [here](https://repl.it/@Eslam3bed/how-nodejs-http-request-send-json-params-to-java-interface)